# LDAP user password is keep on expiring

Tags: ldap

LDAP user password is keep on expiring.
I tried to Reset the password and even disabled/enabled it still facing the same issue.
Please suggest.

Comment: Sounds like you need to update your password expiration policy then. Which LDAP server implementation are we talking about?

Comment: It is only happening with one user account

Comment: Plenty of directory server products have support for granular policies (including password policies applied to a single user), so that doesn't really tell us anything. Which LDAP server implementation are we talking about? OpenLDAP/slapd? FreeIPA? Active Directory? OpenDS?

Comment: I am facing this issue in OpenLDAP